# Prevent snap at the end of SVG color gradient animation

Tags: css, animation, svg, gradient

I am looking to have a smooth animated gradient but I'm stuck at this point with a glitch or **snap at the end of the animation making it jumpy**.

Full code with the snap at the end of aniamtion (after 8 seconds) :

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.page-foot {
  background: #ededed;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #222;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.page-foot-column {
  order: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  
  &:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: right;
  }
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 2734.8 624.7" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 2734.8 624.7" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>  
 <linearGradient id="logo-gradient" x1="1107" x2="1762.2" y1="506.45" y2="-308.45" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <stop stop-color="#FE9637" offset="0"> 
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#FE9637" offset=".1250">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#FF46D5" offset=".2500">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#C030C5" offset=".3750">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#7C52FC" offset=".5000">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#4085F0" offset=".625">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#08B3E5" offset=".750">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#1BD7BB" offset=".875">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#2AF598" offset="1">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
 </linearGradient>
 </defs>
<g>
 <path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" d="m372.1 153.2c-30.2-29.6-66.6-44-109-44-41.8 0-78.5 14.3-108.7 44-30.6 29.6-47.3 66-47.3 107.8v4.6c0 42.1 14.7 79.1 45.5 110.2s68.1 45.8 110.6 45.8c25.3 0 49.5-6.1 72.4-18 11-5.8 21.4-12.8 30.8-21.1s17.7-17.4 24.7-27.5c2.7-4 4.3-8.2 4.3-12.8v-2.4s-0.3-1.2-0.6-2.1c-1.2-6.4-4.6-11.3-10.1-14.7-4-2.4-8.2-3.7-12.5-3.7h-3.4c-7 1.5-12.2 4.6-15.6 9.2-5.2 7.6-11.3 14.4-18 20.1s-14 10.7-21.7 14.7h0.3c-8.2 4-16.5 7-24.7 9.2s-17.1 3.4-26.6 3.4c-29.9 0-55-10.7-76.3-31.1-8.9-8.9-16.5-17.7-21.7-27.8s-8.9-20.8-10.7-32.4h242.2c11.3 0 18.6-5.5 21.7-16.5l-0.3 0.3c0.6-1.5 0.9-2.8 0.9-3.7v-2.8l0.6 0.9v-0.6c0-21.7-4.6-41.5-12.5-59.5-8-18-19.3-34.8-34.3-49.5zm-2.1 87.7h-215.3c5.2-21.7 16.2-40.3 33-55.9v0.3c22-19.5 46.7-29.3 74.5-29.3 14 0 27.5 2.4 40.3 7.3s24.7 11.6 34.8 21.1c7.9 7.3 14.4 16.2 20.1 25.6s10.1 19.5 12.8 30.2l-0.2 0.7zm520.7-117c0.9 2.1 1.2 4.9 1.2 8.2v266.6c0 3.4-0.3 6.1-1.2 8.2s-1.8 4-3 5.5c-5.8 6.1-11.9 9.2-18.3 9.2-5.8 0-11-2.8-15.6-7-4.9-4.6-7.3-9.8-7.3-16.2v-266.6c0-6.4 2.4-11.3 7.3-15.9 4.5-4.2 9.7-6.9 15.4-7 6.7 0.1 13 3.1 18.8 9.4 0.9 1.6 1.8 3.5 2.7 5.6zm-21.3-15h-0.2s-0.1 0-0.2 0h0.4zm148.4 78.2c-21.7 21.7-32.4 47.6-32.4 77.9 0 30.5 10.7 56.5 32.4 77.9 21.4 21.4 47.3 32.1 77.9 32.1 26.6 0 49.8-8.2 69.6-24.4 4.3-3.4 8.5-5.2 13.1-5.2h3.1c6.4 0.9 11.6 4 15.6 9.2h-0.3v0.3 0.3c1.5 2.1 2.8 4.3 3.4 6.7s0.9 5.2 0.9 8.5c-0.3 7-3.4 12.2-8.8 15.3l0.3-0.3c-28.1 23.2-60.5 34.8-97.4 34.8-42.4 0-79.4-14.7-109.9-45.2s-45.5-67.5-45.5-109.9c0-43.1 15.3-79.7 45.5-109.6 30.8-30.2 67.5-45.5 109.9-45.5 17.7 0 34.8 3.1 51.3 8.9s31.4 14.1 45.2 24.7c2.8 2.1 4.9 4.6 6.4 7s2.4 5.8 3.1 10.1c0 2.8-0.6 5.5-1.5 8.2-0.9 2.8-2.1 5.2-3.7 7.6-1.8 2.1-4 4-6.1 5.2s-4.9 2.1-8.2 2.4h-3.1c-4.6 0-9.2-1.5-13.8-4.9-10.1-7.6-21.1-13.7-33-18s-23.8-6.4-36-6.4c-30.4-0.1-56.3 10.6-78 32.3zm640.7 105.7c5.2 9.5 7.6 21.4 7.6 36v6.1c0 2.1 0 4.3-0.3 6.1-0.6 6.1-2.1 12.2-4.9 18.6-2.7 6.4-6.4 12.5-11 18.3-11.6 15-26.6 26.3-44.6 33.9s-39.4 11.3-64.1 11.3c-25.3 0-48.6-5.5-69.6-17.4-10.4-5.8-19.8-12.8-28.4-21.1s-15.6-17.4-21.1-27.5h0.3c-2.4-3.7-3.7-7.6-3.7-11.6v-3.4c0-0.9 0.3-2.1 0.9-3.7 0.9-2.8 2.1-5.2 3.7-7.3 1.5-2.1 4-4 7-5.5l-0.3 0.3c3.7-2.4 7.3-3.7 11-3.7 2.8 0 5.2 0.6 7.3 1.5v-0.3c2.7 0.9 5.2 2.4 7.3 4.3 2.1 1.8 4 4 5.5 6.4 4 6.4 8.6 12.2 13.7 17.7 5.2 5.5 11.3 10.1 18.3 14 7.3 4 15 7 22.6 9.2 7.6 2.1 15.9 3 24.4 3 16.5 0 30.8-2.4 43.1-7.3 12.2-4.9 22-11.6 29-20.1 4-5.2 6.1-9.5 6.7-12.8v-1.8c0.3-1.5 0.6-3 0.6-4.6v-3.7c0-2.8 0-5.2-0.3-7.3s-0.9-4-1.8-5.5c-2.8-4.6-7.6-10.1-15.3-15.3-5.5-4-13.8-6.4-23.8-8.5-10.1-2.1-22-3-36-3-19.2 0-36-1.8-50.4-5.5-14.3-3.7-26-8.9-35.1-15.6-7-5.2-13.1-10.7-18.3-16.2s-9.2-11-11.9-16.5c-4-8.2-6.4-19.2-5.8-33l0.3-7.9c0.3-5.8 1.8-11.9 4.6-18.3s6.4-12.5 11-18.6c11.6-15 26.6-26.3 44.6-33.9s39.4-11.6 63.8-11.6c16.5 0 32.4 2.8 47.6 8.2 15.3 5.5 29 13.1 41.5 22.9 2.7 2.1 4.9 4.3 6.4 6.4s2.4 5.5 2.8 10.1c0 3.1-0.3 5.8-0.9 8.2s-1.8 4.6-3.7 6.7c-2.1 2.8-4.3 4.6-6.7 5.8s-5.8 2.4-10.1 2.4c-5.5 0.3-10.4-1.5-14.3-4.3-0.3 0-0.6-0.3-0.9-0.6-17.4-14.7-37.6-22-60.5-22-16.8 0-31.2 2.4-43.1 7.3s-21.4 11.6-28.7 20.1v-0.3c-4 5.2-6.1 9.5-6.4 12.8v3.7c0 7.9 0.3 13.1 1.2 15.6v-0.6c2.4 4.6 7.6 9.8 15.6 15.3 5.8 3.7 13.7 6.7 23.8 8.9 10.1 2.1 22 3.4 35.4 3.4 18.9 0 35.7 1.8 50.1 5.2 14.3 3.4 26.3 8.2 35.7 14.7 6.4 4.6 11.9 9.5 16.8 14.4s8.9 10.1 11.9 15.3h-0.3l0.2 2.2zm79.2-181.7h-0.2s-0.1 0-0.2 0h0.4zm21.3 14.9c0.9 2.1 1.2 4.9 1.2 8.2v264.5c0 3.4-0.3 6.1-1.2 8.2s-1.8 4-3.1 5.5c-5.8 6.1-11.9 9.2-18.3 9.2-5.8 0-11-2.8-15.6-7-4.9-4.6-7.3-9.8-7.3-16.2v-264.4c0-6.4 2.4-11.3 7.3-15.9 4.5-4.2 9.7-6.9 15.4-7 6.7 0.1 13 3.1 18.8 9.4 1 1.6 1.9 3.4 2.8 5.5zm690.6 27.2c-30.2-29.6-66.6-44-109-44-41.8 0-78.5 14.3-108.7 44-30.6 29.6-47.3 66-47.3 107.8v4.6c0 42.1 14.6 79.1 45.5 110.2 30.8 31.1 68.1 45.8 110.6 45.8 25.3 0 49.5-6.1 72.4-18 11-5.8 21.4-12.8 30.8-21.1 9.5-8.2 17.7-17.4 24.7-27.5 2.7-4 4.3-8.2 4.3-12.8v-2.4s-0.3-1.2-0.6-2.1c-1.2-6.4-4.6-11.3-10.1-14.7-4-2.4-8.2-3.7-12.5-3.7h-3.4c-7 1.5-12.2 4.6-15.6 9.2-5.2 7.6-11.3 14.4-18 20.1s-14 10.7-21.7 14.7h0.3c-8.2 4-16.5 7-24.7 9.2s-17.1 3.4-26.6 3.4c-29.9 0-55-10.7-76.3-31.1-8.9-8.9-16.5-17.7-21.7-27.8s-8.9-20.8-10.7-32.4h242.2c11.3 0 18.6-5.5 21.7-16.5l-0.3 0.3c0.6-1.5 0.9-2.8 0.9-3.7v-2.8l0.6 0.9v-0.6c0-21.7-4.6-41.5-12.5-59.5-8.1-18-19.4-34.8-34.3-49.5zm-2.2 87.7h-215.3c5.2-21.7 16.2-40.3 33-55.9v0.3c22-19.5 46.7-29.3 74.5-29.3 14 0 27.5 2.4 40.3 7.3s24.7 11.6 34.8 21.1c7.9 7.3 14.4 16.2 20.2 25.6 5.8 9.5 10.1 19.5 12.8 30.2l-0.3 0.7zm213.5-240.7c2.3 0 4.3 0.9 6 2.5 1.7 1.5 2.6 3.5 2.6 6.1 0 2.2-0.9 4.2-2.6 5.9-1.8 1.7-3.8 2.4-6.1 2.4h-11.4v45c0 1.2-0.2 2.3-0.7 3.3-0.4 1-1 1.9-1.8 2.7-1.7 1.7-3.6 2.6-5.9 2.6s-4.3-0.8-6.1-2.4c-1.7-1.7-2.4-3.7-2.4-6.1v-45h-11.5c-2.1 0-4.1-0.8-5.9-2.4-1.7-1.9-2.6-3.9-2.6-6 0-2.3 0.9-4.3 2.6-6s3.6-2.5 5.9-2.5c0.1-0.1 39.9-0.1 39.9-0.1zm73.4 62.2c0 2.1-0.8 4.1-2.6 6-1.7 1.8-3.8 2.7-6 2.7-2.3 0-4.3-0.9-6-2.7-1.8-1.8-2.7-3.8-2.7-6v-26.2c-0.2 0.3-0.4 0.7-0.7 1-0.2 0.3-0.4 0.7-0.7 1l-1.4 2.3c-0.4 0.8-1 1.5-1.6 2.3-1 1-2 1.8-3 2.4s-2.3 1-3.9 1c-1.4 0-2.7-0.3-3.8-1s-2.1-1.5-3.1-2.5l-4.8-6.8v26.3c0 2.3-0.8 4.3-2.3 6-0.8 0.8-1.7 1.4-2.7 2s-2.1 0.8-3.3 0.8c-2.3 0-4.3-0.9-6.1-2.8-1.7-1.7-2.4-3.7-2.4-6v-53.3c0-2.1 0.6-3.8 1.6-5s2.4-2.2 4.3-3h-0.1c0.6-0.2 1.1-0.3 1.6-0.4s0.9-0.1 1.3-0.1c1.6 0 2.9 0.3 4 1s2.1 1.5 2.9 2.7l2.1 3.1c0.8 1.1 1.3 2 1.9 2.8v-0.2l2.1 3.2 2.1 3 2.2 3.1 2.8 3.6 6.6-9.5 6.4-9.4v0.1c1.7-2.5 4-3.9 7-3.9 1 0 1.9 0.2 2.7 0.5l-0.1-0.1c4.1 1.2 6.1 4 6.1 8.3v53.4l-0.4 0.3zm-208.3-62.4h-2448.7c-42.6 0-77.3 34.7-77.3 77.3v374.1c0 42.6 34.7 77.3 77.3 77.3h73.6l84.9 84.9c7.1 7.1 16.6 11 26.6 11 10.1 0 19.5-3.9 26.6-11l85-84.9h2152c42.6 0 77.3-34.7 77.3-77.3v-374.1c0-42.6-34.6-77.3-77.3-77.3zm33.6 451.4c0 18.5-15.1 33.6-33.6 33.6h-2004.8v-111.6c4.9 5.2 9.5 9.5 13.8 12.8 4.3 3.4 9.5 7 15.3 10.7 24.1 15 51 22.3 80.6 22.3 43 0 79.1-15.6 109-45.5 30.2-30.2 45.8-66.6 45.8-109.6 0-21.4-4-41.2-11.9-59.5s-19.2-34.5-34.2-49.5-31.2-26.3-49.5-34.2-38.2-11.9-59.9-11.9l1.8 0.3c-21.1 0-40.9 4-59.5 11.9s-35.4 19.2-50.4 33.9-26.3 31.1-34.2 49.5c-7.9 18.3-11.9 38.2-11.9 59.5v220.9h-120l-93.5 93.5-93.5-93.5h-91.7c-18.5 0-33.6-15.1-33.6-33.6v-374.1c0-18.5 15.1-33.6 33.6-33.6h1993.9v113.2c-4.3-4.3-8.9-8.2-13.7-12.2-4.9-4-10.1-7.6-15.9-11-24.7-15-51.9-22.6-81.8-22.6-43.1 0-79.7 15.6-110.6 46.4s-46.4 67.5-46.4 110.9 15.6 80 46.4 110.9 67.5 45.8 110.6 45.8c43.4 0 80.3-15 110.8-45.8 30.8-30.8 46.4-67.8 46.4-110.9v-224.7h409.1c18.5 0 33.6 15.1 33.6 33.6l-0.1 374.1zm-2037.8-186.7c0-30.2 10.7-56.2 32.4-77.9 21.4-21.7 47.3-32.4 77.6-32.4 30.8 0 56.5 10.7 77.9 32.4 21.1 21.4 32.1 47.3 32.1 77.6 0 30.2-10.7 56.2-32.1 77.6s-47.3 32.1-77.5 32.1l-0.3 0.6c-30.2 0-56.2-10.7-77.6-32.1-21.8-21.7-32.5-47.7-32.5-77.9zm1359.1 81.5c-21.7-21.7-32.7-47.9-32.7-78.8s11-57.1 32.7-78.8 47.9-32.7 78.8-32.7c31.4 0 57.4 11 78.8 32.7 21.4 22 32.4 47.9 32.4 79.1 0 30.8-10.7 57.1-32.4 78.8s-47.9 32.7-78.8 32.7v-0.3c-30.2 0-56.5-10.7-78.8-32.7z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Here is a [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/matbe81/pen/RwWgPav)  for you convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **prevent the snap at the end of the color gradient animation**, you need it to end at the same state as the start state. Example :

```
<animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
```

In the animate tag, the **first and last colors in the value attribute are the same** (`#FE9637`).
*Here is a full code example with the corrections to the value attributes in the animate tags :*

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.page-foot {
  background: #ededed;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #222;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.page-foot-column {
  order: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  &:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: right;
  }
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 2734.8 624.7" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 2734.8 624.7" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>  
 <linearGradient id="logo-gradient" x1="1107" x2="1762.2" y1="506.45" y2="-308.45" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <stop stop-color="#FE9637" offset="0"> 
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#FE9637" offset=".1250">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#FF46D5" offset=".2500">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#C030C5" offset=".3750">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#7C52FC" offset=".5000">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#4085F0" offset=".625">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#08B3E5" offset=".750">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#1BD7BB" offset=".875">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598;#1BD7BB" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
  <stop stop-color="#2AF598" offset="1">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#2AF598;#1BD7BB;#08B3E5;#4085F0;#7C52FC;#C030C5;#FF46D5;#FE9637;#FE9637;#FF46D5;#C030C5;#7C52FC;#4085F0;#08B3E5;#1BD7BB;#2AF598" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </stop>
 </linearGradient>
 </defs>
<g>
 <path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" d="m372.1 153.2c-30.2-29.6-66.6-44-109-44-41.8 0-78.5 14.3-108.7 44-30.6 29.6-47.3 66-47.3 107.8v4.6c0 42.1 14.7 79.1 45.5 110.2s68.1 45.8 110.6 45.8c25.3 0 49.5-6.1 72.4-18 11-5.8 21.4-12.8 30.8-21.1s17.7-17.4 24.7-27.5c2.7-4 4.3-8.2 4.3-12.8v-2.4s-0.3-1.2-0.6-2.1c-1.2-6.4-4.6-11.3-10.1-14.7-4-2.4-8.2-3.7-12.5-3.7h-3.4c-7 1.5-12.2 4.6-15.6 9.2-5.2 7.6-11.3 14.4-18 20.1s-14 10.7-21.7 14.7h0.3c-8.2 4-16.5 7-24.7 9.2s-17.1 3.4-26.6 3.4c-29.9 0-55-10.7-76.3-31.1-8.9-8.9-16.5-17.7-21.7-27.8s-8.9-20.8-10.7-32.4h242.2c11.3 0 18.6-5.5 21.7-16.5l-0.3 0.3c0.6-1.5 0.9-2.8 0.9-3.7v-2.8l0.6 0.9v-0.6c0-21.7-4.6-41.5-12.5-59.5-8-18-19.3-34.8-34.3-49.5zm-2.1 87.7h-215.3c5.2-21.7 16.2-40.3 33-55.9v0.3c22-19.5 46.7-29.3 74.5-29.3 14 0 27.5 2.4 40.3 7.3s24.7 11.6 34.8 21.1c7.9 7.3 14.4 16.2 20.1 25.6s10.1 19.5 12.8 30.2l-0.2 0.7zm520.7-117c0.9 2.1 1.2 4.9 1.2 8.2v266.6c0 3.4-0.3 6.1-1.2 8.2s-1.8 4-3 5.5c-5.8 6.1-11.9 9.2-18.3 9.2-5.8 0-11-2.8-15.6-7-4.9-4.6-7.3-9.8-7.3-16.2v-266.6c0-6.4 2.4-11.3 7.3-15.9 4.5-4.2 9.7-6.9 15.4-7 6.7 0.1 13 3.1 18.8 9.4 0.9 1.6 1.8 3.5 2.7 5.6zm-21.3-15h-0.2s-0.1 0-0.2 0h0.4zm148.4 78.2c-21.7 21.7-32.4 47.6-32.4 77.9 0 30.5 10.7 56.5 32.4 77.9 21.4 21.4 47.3 32.1 77.9 32.1 26.6 0 49.8-8.2 69.6-24.4 4.3-3.4 8.5-5.2 13.1-5.2h3.1c6.4 0.9 11.6 4 15.6 9.2h-0.3v0.3 0.3c1.5 2.1 2.8 4.3 3.4 6.7s0.9 5.2 0.9 8.5c-0.3 7-3.4 12.2-8.8 15.3l0.3-0.3c-28.1 23.2-60.5 34.8-97.4 34.8-42.4 0-79.4-14.7-109.9-45.2s-45.5-67.5-45.5-109.9c0-43.1 15.3-79.7 45.5-109.6 30.8-30.2 67.5-45.5 109.9-45.5 17.7 0 34.8 3.1 51.3 8.9s31.4 14.1 45.2 24.7c2.8 2.1 4.9 4.6 6.4 7s2.4 5.8 3.1 10.1c0 2.8-0.6 5.5-1.5 8.2-0.9 2.8-2.1 5.2-3.7 7.6-1.8 2.1-4 4-6.1 5.2s-4.9 2.1-8.2 2.4h-3.1c-4.6 0-9.2-1.5-13.8-4.9-10.1-7.6-21.1-13.7-33-18s-23.8-6.4-36-6.4c-30.4-0.1-56.3 10.6-78 32.3zm640.7 105.7c5.2 9.5 7.6 21.4 7.6 36v6.1c0 2.1 0 4.3-0.3 6.1-0.6 6.1-2.1 12.2-4.9 18.6-2.7 6.4-6.4 12.5-11 18.3-11.6 15-26.6 26.3-44.6 33.9s-39.4 11.3-64.1 11.3c-25.3 0-48.6-5.5-69.6-17.4-10.4-5.8-19.8-12.8-28.4-21.1s-15.6-17.4-21.1-27.5h0.3c-2.4-3.7-3.7-7.6-3.7-11.6v-3.4c0-0.9 0.3-2.1 0.9-3.7 0.9-2.8 2.1-5.2 3.7-7.3 1.5-2.1 4-4 7-5.5l-0.3 0.3c3.7-2.4 7.3-3.7 11-3.7 2.8 0 5.2 0.6 7.3 1.5v-0.3c2.7 0.9 5.2 2.4 7.3 4.3 2.1 1.8 4 4 5.5 6.4 4 6.4 8.6 12.2 13.7 17.7 5.2 5.5 11.3 10.1 18.3 14 7.3 4 15 7 22.6 9.2 7.6 2.1 15.9 3 24.4 3 16.5 0 30.8-2.4 43.1-7.3 12.2-4.9 22-11.6 29-20.1 4-5.2 6.1-9.5 6.7-12.8v-1.8c0.3-1.5 0.6-3 0.6-4.6v-3.7c0-2.8 0-5.2-0.3-7.3s-0.9-4-1.8-5.5c-2.8-4.6-7.6-10.1-15.3-15.3-5.5-4-13.8-6.4-23.8-8.5-10.1-2.1-22-3-36-3-19.2 0-36-1.8-50.4-5.5-14.3-3.7-26-8.9-35.1-15.6-7-5.2-13.1-10.7-18.3-16.2s-9.2-11-11.9-16.5c-4-8.2-6.4-19.2-5.8-33l0.3-7.9c0.3-5.8 1.8-11.9 4.6-18.3s6.4-12.5 11-18.6c11.6-15 26.6-26.3 44.6-33.9s39.4-11.6 63.8-11.6c16.5 0 32.4 2.8 47.6 8.2 15.3 5.5 29 13.1 41.5 22.9 2.7 2.1 4.9 4.3 6.4 6.4s2.4 5.5 2.8 10.1c0 3.1-0.3 5.8-0.9 8.2s-1.8 4.6-3.7 6.7c-2.1 2.8-4.3 4.6-6.7 5.8s-5.8 2.4-10.1 2.4c-5.5 0.3-10.4-1.5-14.3-4.3-0.3 0-0.6-0.3-0.9-0.6-17.4-14.7-37.6-22-60.5-22-16.8 0-31.2 2.4-43.1 7.3s-21.4 11.6-28.7 20.1v-0.3c-4 5.2-6.1 9.5-6.4 12.8v3.7c0 7.9 0.3 13.1 1.2 15.6v-0.6c2.4 4.6 7.6 9.8 15.6 15.3 5.8 3.7 13.7 6.7 23.8 8.9 10.1 2.1 22 3.4 35.4 3.4 18.9 0 35.7 1.8 50.1 5.2 14.3 3.4 26.3 8.2 35.7 14.7 6.4 4.6 11.9 9.5 16.8 14.4s8.9 10.1 11.9 15.3h-0.3l0.2 2.2zm79.2-181.7h-0.2s-0.1 0-0.2 0h0.4zm21.3 14.9c0.9 2.1 1.2 4.9 1.2 8.2v264.5c0 3.4-0.3 6.1-1.2 8.2s-1.8 4-3.1 5.5c-5.8 6.1-11.9 9.2-18.3 9.2-5.8 0-11-2.8-15.6-7-4.9-4.6-7.3-9.8-7.3-16.2v-264.4c0-6.4 2.4-11.3 7.3-15.9 4.5-4.2 9.7-6.9 15.4-7 6.7 0.1 13 3.1 18.8 9.4 1 1.6 1.9 3.4 2.8 5.5zm690.6 27.2c-30.2-29.6-66.6-44-109-44-41.8 0-78.5 14.3-108.7 44-30.6 29.6-47.3 66-47.3 107.8v4.6c0 42.1 14.6 79.1 45.5 110.2 30.8 31.1 68.1 45.8 110.6 45.8 25.3 0 49.5-6.1 72.4-18 11-5.8 21.4-12.8 30.8-21.1 9.5-8.2 17.7-17.4 24.7-27.5 2.7-4 4.3-8.2 4.3-12.8v-2.4s-0.3-1.2-0.6-2.1c-1.2-6.4-4.6-11.3-10.1-14.7-4-2.4-8.2-3.7-12.5-3.7h-3.4c-7 1.5-12.2 4.6-15.6 9.2-5.2 7.6-11.3 14.4-18 20.1s-14 10.7-21.7 14.7h0.3c-8.2 4-16.5 7-24.7 9.2s-17.1 3.4-26.6 3.4c-29.9 0-55-10.7-76.3-31.1-8.9-8.9-16.5-17.7-21.7-27.8s-8.9-20.8-10.7-32.4h242.2c11.3 0 18.6-5.5 21.7-16.5l-0.3 0.3c0.6-1.5 0.9-2.8 0.9-3.7v-2.8l0.6 0.9v-0.6c0-21.7-4.6-41.5-12.5-59.5-8.1-18-19.4-34.8-34.3-49.5zm-2.2 87.7h-215.3c5.2-21.7 16.2-40.3 33-55.9v0.3c22-19.5 46.7-29.3 74.5-29.3 14 0 27.5 2.4 40.3 7.3s24.7 11.6 34.8 21.1c7.9 7.3 14.4 16.2 20.2 25.6 5.8 9.5 10.1 19.5 12.8 30.2l-0.3 0.7zm213.5-240.7c2.3 0 4.3 0.9 6 2.5 1.7 1.5 2.6 3.5 2.6 6.1 0 2.2-0.9 4.2-2.6 5.9-1.8 1.7-3.8 2.4-6.1 2.4h-11.4v45c0 1.2-0.2 2.3-0.7 3.3-0.4 1-1 1.9-1.8 2.7-1.7 1.7-3.6 2.6-5.9 2.6s-4.3-0.8-6.1-2.4c-1.7-1.7-2.4-3.7-2.4-6.1v-45h-11.5c-2.1 0-4.1-0.8-5.9-2.4-1.7-1.9-2.6-3.9-2.6-6 0-2.3 0.9-4.3 2.6-6s3.6-2.5 5.9-2.5c0.1-0.1 39.9-0.1 39.9-0.1zm73.4 62.2c0 2.1-0.8 4.1-2.6 6-1.7 1.8-3.8 2.7-6 2.7-2.3 0-4.3-0.9-6-2.7-1.8-1.8-2.7-3.8-2.7-6v-26.2c-0.2 0.3-0.4 0.7-0.7 1-0.2 0.3-0.4 0.7-0.7 1l-1.4 2.3c-0.4 0.8-1 1.5-1.6 2.3-1 1-2 1.8-3 2.4s-2.3 1-3.9 1c-1.4 0-2.7-0.3-3.8-1s-2.1-1.5-3.1-2.5l-4.8-6.8v26.3c0 2.3-0.8 4.3-2.3 6-0.8 0.8-1.7 1.4-2.7 2s-2.1 0.8-3.3 0.8c-2.3 0-4.3-0.9-6.1-2.8-1.7-1.7-2.4-3.7-2.4-6v-53.3c0-2.1 0.6-3.8 1.6-5s2.4-2.2 4.3-3h-0.1c0.6-0.2 1.1-0.3 1.6-0.4s0.9-0.1 1.3-0.1c1.6 0 2.9 0.3 4 1s2.1 1.5 2.9 2.7l2.1 3.1c0.8 1.1 1.3 2 1.9 2.8v-0.2l2.1 3.2 2.1 3 2.2 3.1 2.8 3.6 6.6-9.5 6.4-9.4v0.1c1.7-2.5 4-3.9 7-3.9 1 0 1.9 0.2 2.7 0.5l-0.1-0.1c4.1 1.2 6.1 4 6.1 8.3v53.4l-0.4 0.3zm-208.3-62.4h-2448.7c-42.6 0-77.3 34.7-77.3 77.3v374.1c0 42.6 34.7 77.3 77.3 77.3h73.6l84.9 84.9c7.1 7.1 16.6 11 26.6 11 10.1 0 19.5-3.9 26.6-11l85-84.9h2152c42.6 0 77.3-34.7 77.3-77.3v-374.1c0-42.6-34.6-77.3-77.3-77.3zm33.6 451.4c0 18.5-15.1 33.6-33.6 33.6h-2004.8v-111.6c4.9 5.2 9.5 9.5 13.8 12.8 4.3 3.4 9.5 7 15.3 10.7 24.1 15 51 22.3 80.6 22.3 43 0 79.1-15.6 109-45.5 30.2-30.2 45.8-66.6 45.8-109.6 0-21.4-4-41.2-11.9-59.5s-19.2-34.5-34.2-49.5-31.2-26.3-49.5-34.2-38.2-11.9-59.9-11.9l1.8 0.3c-21.1 0-40.9 4-59.5 11.9s-35.4 19.2-50.4 33.9-26.3 31.1-34.2 49.5c-7.9 18.3-11.9 38.2-11.9 59.5v220.9h-120l-93.5 93.5-93.5-93.5h-91.7c-18.5 0-33.6-15.1-33.6-33.6v-374.1c0-18.5 15.1-33.6 33.6-33.6h1993.9v113.2c-4.3-4.3-8.9-8.2-13.7-12.2-4.9-4-10.1-7.6-15.9-11-24.7-15-51.9-22.6-81.8-22.6-43.1 0-79.7 15.6-110.6 46.4s-46.4 67.5-46.4 110.9 15.6 80 46.4 110.9 67.5 45.8 110.6 45.8c43.4 0 80.3-15 110.8-45.8 30.8-30.8 46.4-67.8 46.4-110.9v-224.7h409.1c18.5 0 33.6 15.1 33.6 33.6l-0.1 374.1zm-2037.8-186.7c0-30.2 10.7-56.2 32.4-77.9 21.4-21.7 47.3-32.4 77.6-32.4 30.8 0 56.5 10.7 77.9 32.4 21.1 21.4 32.1 47.3 32.1 77.6 0 30.2-10.7 56.2-32.1 77.6s-47.3 32.1-77.5 32.1l-0.3 0.6c-30.2 0-56.2-10.7-77.6-32.1-21.8-21.7-32.5-47.7-32.5-77.9zm1359.1 81.5c-21.7-21.7-32.7-47.9-32.7-78.8s11-57.1 32.7-78.8 47.9-32.7 78.8-32.7c31.4 0 57.4 11 78.8 32.7 21.4 22 32.4 47.9 32.4 79.1 0 30.8-10.7 57.1-32.4 78.8s-47.9 32.7-78.8 32.7v-0.3c-30.2 0-56.5-10.7-78.8-32.7z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: No more glitch! Thanks ! But there is still something strange: the gradient colors are not proportional. There should be 8 differents colors. Can you optimize that?

Comment: change the x1 on your linearGradient to 0 if you want to show the entire gradient at once.